# Beginner help for understanding Haskell List Comprehension syntax

Tags: haskell, syntax

Here is the code I'm trying to understand.

```
let triple = [ (a,b,c) | c <- [1..10], a <- [1..c], b <- [1..a], a^2 + b^2 == c^2]
```

My question is in which order does Haskell evaluate each expression?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could roughly translate this to imperative pseudocode like so:

```
for c in 1..10
  for a in 1..c
    for b in 1..a
      if a^2 + b^2 == c^2
        put (a,b,c) on end of triple
```

except that it will run lazily as elements are requested by whatever consumes the list.

List comprehensions are effectively a fairly simple syntactic sugar on top of the list monad. If you want more information about how they're interpreted you may want to look there.

Answer (score 5):

> In which order does Haskell evaluate each expression?

As general rule, the answer to this question is

> It's none of your business.

Worrying about what order things are evaluated in is not the right way to think about what your Haskell program will do. In Java, that matters a lot, because evaluation can have side effects. In Haskell, the evaluation order does not affect the results (weird corners aside).

The key to thinking about list comprehensions is to think about the *nesting* order, not the *evaluation* order. The leftmost terms of the list comprehension are the outermost ones.